# MicroK8s containers unable to start. All pods stuck on "ContainerCreating" state. Ubuntu 20.10 RP4

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, raspberry-pi, microk8s, ubuntu-20.10

I've been Googling and going through logs to try and solve this, but I can't seem to get microk8s to work on my Raspberry Pi, running Ubuntu 20.10

I snap install v1.15
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.15/stable

I can confirm that microk8s.status returns that it is running.
kubectl get nodes --namespace kube-system returns:

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
mydnsname   Ready    <none>   22h   v1.15.11
```

I have installed the following enabled: dashboard
I had dashboard dns ingress - installed but the same issue was present.

kubectl get all --all-namespaces returns

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                  READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/heapster-v1.5.2-c4dcfd9f8-kl5g5                   0/4     ContainerCreating   0          68s
kube-system   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-c775bf88b-pmhz6              0/1     ContainerCreating   0          68s
kube-system   pod/monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v4-6f74479987-rd5ck   0/2     ContainerCreating   0          68s


NAMESPACE     NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
default       service/kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP             18h
kube-system   service/heapster               ClusterIP   10.152.183.195   <none>        80/TCP              68s
kube-system   service/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.152.183.171   <none>        443/TCP             68s
kube-system   service/monitoring-grafana     ClusterIP   10.152.183.120   <none>        80/TCP              68s
kube-system   service/monitoring-influxdb    ClusterIP   10.152.183.175   <none>        8083/TCP,8086/TCP   68s


NAMESPACE     NAME                                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/heapster-v1.5.2                  0/1     1            0           68s
kube-system   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard             0/1     1            0           68s
kube-system   deployment.apps/monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v4   0/1     1            0           68s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/heapster-v1.5.2-c4dcfd9f8                   1         1         0       68s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-c775bf88b              1         1         0       68s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v4-6f74479987   1         1         0       68s
```

kubectl describe pods kubernetes-dashboard-c775bf88b-pmhz6 --namespace kube-system returns

```
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m26s (x3 over 2m54s)   kubelet, mydnsname  (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container: failed to create containerd task: failed to mount rootfs component &{overlay overlay [workdir=/var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/1386/work upperdir=/var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/1386/fs lowerdir=/var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/2/fs]}: invalid argument: unknown
  Warning  MissingClusterDNS       2m14s (x13 over 4m58s)  kubelet, mydnsname  pod: "kubernetes-dashboard-c775bf88b-pmhz6_kube-system(777df7aa-d4de-40f0-8275-70b36d2e5029)". kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to "Default" policy.
```

I have checked and I am not using ZFS as my filesystem for my main partition, I'm using overlayfs
df -Th

```
Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none           overlay   59G   21G   36G  37% /
tmpfs          tmpfs    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs    743M  1.2M  742M   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs    5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs    4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs    372M  104K  372M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Therefore I'm not sure why containerd can't mount or has an issue, considering that containerd doesn't have any issues with overlayfs.

Have tried microk8s.reset and uninstalling and reinstalling, and tried a few different versions and still to no avail.

Any ideas or assistance is greatly appreciated as I'm keen to get a local kubernetes setup for local dev!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try microk8s enable dns, then reset the cluster

Comment: Hi Furkan, I tried enabling DNS
microk8s enable dns

Then restarted microk8s - is this what you mean by reset the cluster?
microk8s stop && microk8s start

CoreDNS container still displaying the same error and ContainerCreating status.
"Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error"

Thanks

Comment: no I meant "microk8s reset" It should reinstall everything. microk8s enable dns is ok. But the thing you did was also similar. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've tried a microk8s reset and enabling dns again and it still has the same error. Plus I've tried reset and uninstalling microk8s and the same issue always occurs. I think it might be something to do with containerd failing to mount root file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue was with microk8s, specifically containerd not working with squashFS filesystem with overlay.

The reason for my Ubuntu install using SquashFS was that I was using Berryboot to support multiple OS installations.

I switched to Pinn, which supports ext4 filesystem, which works with containerd and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04.

After installing microk8s, the node starts running and containers are all now running correctly.